# Class compiles but not available at run time: Robot() shows java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I was trying to create a simple project using JavaFX Robot. But faced a InvocationTargetException error. I also tried doing

```
Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
```

as per another old question. But that resulted in can't resolve Glassrobot to javafx.scene.robot.Robot. As it seems the same code runs in my friends computer just fine.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.robot.Robot;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        Robot robot = new Robot();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But I faced this error

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.sun.glass.ui.GlassRobot com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.createRobot()'
    at javafx.scene.robot.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:78)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:11)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also this is my first question. So please ignore if I fell short to produce a good question.

Comment: what is your fx version? the fx robot was added recently - don't recall when exactly, though

Comment: ... in second thought: if it compiles it should be available .. hmm

Comment: @kleopatra My JavaFX version is 11

Comment: It looks like your build path and your runtime classpath are not the same. In runtime you may be running with an older JavaFX.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem. It is running now.

Comment: @RealSkeptic consider posting your comment as answer